# Excel VBA - Loop Through Worksheet, Copy Cells, Paste into New Worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

## **Summary**

Hello, I'm new to VBA and I need help with creating a loop to copy/paste specific cells into newly created worksheets. I currently have code to create a new worksheet based off of a master worksheet and rename the "new" worksheet to a cell value.

The code I currently have basically does the following (see code below):

1. Calculates the number of rows in column 2 from a worksheet called Import
2. Creates a new worksheet based on the worksheet called Master
3. Names the new worksheet tab the data found within column 2 from the worksheet called import

## **Description**

I trying to accomplish the following:

1. Starting with the 2nd row in the Import worksheet, copy specific cells

   - The Import worksheet will have multiple rows and columns
   - Identified columns I will need to copy are A, B, O, Q, Y, BG, BW, CB, CC, CD, CE, CH, CJ
2. Paste into specific cells in a newly created worksheet

   - Current code exists for creating new worksheet, see **Code** below
   - Identified cells I need to paste  into are B7:C8, E7:F8, I7:J8, C14:E14, C15:E15, C16:E16, H14:J14, H16:J16, E20:J21, E22:J22, E23:J23, A27:J33, A37:J43
3. Move to the next row in the Import worksheet and repeat steps 1, 2, and 3

## **Code**

```
Sub makeNewSheets()

' Declare variables sh1 = Master worksheet
' sh2 = Import
' c = column range found in Import worksheet
Dim sh1 As Worksheet
Dim sh2 As Worksheet
Dim c As Range

' Set sh1 to Master worksheet
Set sh1 = Sheets("Master")
' Set sh2 to Import worksheet
Set sh2 = Sheets("Import")

' Count each number of filled rows in column 2, for every row counted create a new worksheet
' based on the Master worksheet and give the tab the associated value found in the Import worksheet
    For Each c In sh2.Range("B2", sh2.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp))
        sh1.Copy Before:=sh1
        ActiveSheet.Name = c.Value
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: You should first define how many cell are you copying in each loop. I mean, you said *I will need to copy are A, B, O, Q, Y, BG, BW, CB, CC, CD, CE, CH, CJ* starting at row 2, so I guess you are copying 1 row in each loop, but then you say *I need to paste into are B7:C8, E7:F8, I7:J8, C14:E14, C15:E15, C16:E16, H14:J14, H16:J16, E20:J21, E22:J22, E23:J23, A27:J33, A37:J43* So you want to paste some cells of same row into **diferent** rows of another sheet? or how?

Comment: I guess I wasn't clear enough, my apologies.

In my current code I am creating new worksheets basically off of a list contained in an imported worksheet (this piece of code is provided). 

In addition to the above action, I want to copy specific cells from the Import worksheet into the newly created worksheet. Then go to the next row in the Import worksheet, copy specific cells, and paste them into the newly created worksheet. I want to repeat this action until I'm at the end of the Import spreadsheet.

Comment: To copy a cell you can do just something like `sh1.Range("A1").Copy sh2.Range("C100")` This will copy cell A1 from first worksheet to cell C100 from second worksheet.

Comment: Hi - I'd be happy to help but the requirement not 100% clear to me:

what is the relationship between 

"Identified columns I will need to copy are A, B, O, Q, Y, BG, BW, CB, CC, CD, CE, CH, CJ"

and 

"Identified cells I need to paste into are B7:C8, E7:F8, I7:J8, C14:E14, C15:E15, C16:E16, H14:J14, H16:J16, E20:J21, E22:J22, E23:J23, A27:J33, A37:J43"


can you clarify that? thanks

Comment: Here goes... The identified columns "A, B, O,..." are columns from the Import worksheet. the identified cells "B7:C8, E7:F8,..." are cells in the Master worksheet. The Import worksheet will have multiple rows and I believe I need a loop to run until there are no more rows left with data; I need the loop to copy data from the Import worksheet and paste the data into the newly created worksheet cells. The new created worksheet is a replication of the Master sheet. I provided the code where I can create replications of the Master sheet and correctly name the worksheet tabs.